# Wanted to test my app on device through app store without review

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

I have a small problem but couldn't find solution for that. I have founded Questions like this but the answers are not upto my requirement or may be i am not able to understand them correctly.

**Problem :-**

I have my app on app store(Reading PDF and downloading them). It is working fine for downloading small pdf's and showing them, but when it comes to download large pdf's my app crashes or abort. One more strange thing my app works fine on simulator with huge pdf's also but not on devices.
Now, i have made some changes in my code and i wanted to test it on device.I can not deploy it directly on device as i am not having iphone right now. so i want it to upload on appstore for testing purpose without giving it for Apple review.

i want to know the whole procedure how to do it.Starting from whether i have to create a new account for that **to** how to test it on device.Url's will also be helpful.

And ya my device is not having any memory issues. Thanks.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't sell an experimental piece of equipment in any store, so you also do not upload things for debugging to the app store.

If you want to test it on someone's device why don't you just create a provisioning profile and send him the app? Then he can install it through **itunes**.

Also you should write the data you received ( while downloading ) to the disk every now and then, otherwise you are going to keep having this issue of running out of memory.

Something like:

```
// received data
NSFileHandle *yourFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
[yourFileHandle writeData:dataChunk];
// get rid of data chunk
```

Comment: guys, sorry if i am wrong, but is there any way that we can put our app on App store which will be applicable for some devices only(something like demo for inApp Purchase).Actually, i am making app on XCode 3.2 and the device is having IOS 5. so it is not allowing me to deploy it directly through profiles, so i was thinking to test it through downloading from appstore without sending it to review. sorry if i am troubling anyone :)

Comment: Very short answer: NO WAY. And you should really update to iOs5 as soon as possible anyway ...

Comment: @mAc yeah.. xcode 4 is so bad that I would like to use xcode 3.2 as well, but the problem is that I really need to develop stuff. Just update and leave a copy of xcode 3.2 on your system ( won't damage anything ).

Comment: @Antwan van Houdt :- hehehe... ya i also love 3.2 as i am fearing to upload 4.Tell me one thing when i will upgrade my xcode to 4, will my apps made on 3.2 will work fine?

Comment: @TheEye :- Great... Short and straight answer.... :( but sad for my problem.... and ya i am soon going to upgrade it to Xcode 4....

Comment: @mAc yeah it will work, its just the same but then slower, more bugs and more whining. With xcode 4 you can also make use of LLVM 3.0, which is a really nice compiler compared to GCC4.2 you get with xcode3.2

Comment: dude, i am a little noob in this, bt how can i change my compiler to LLVM 3.0 from GCC...

Comment: after working a while with XCode 4 now, it has some nice features. I just don't understand they don't get rid of some really annoying bugs that seem to be in there from the start, like not saving any changes to keyboard shortcuts ... and it does crash quite often indeed.

Comment: @TheEye and the performance is really annoying me, just use another code editor for a while and you will notice how nice it is to be able to scroll without lag and being able to use keyboard repeat without the editor using 200% ( both cores ).

Comment: sry for late.. :D but i think... it is not possible :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't distribute your app via the app store without going through the app store review process. You might want to read up about ad hoc distribution of your apps. I've used [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) successfully in the past for ad-hoc distribution.

Comment: guys, sorry if i am wrong, but is there any way that we can put our app on App store which will be applicable for some devices only(something like demo for inApp Purchase).Actually, i am making app on XCode 3.2 and the device is having IOS 5. so it is not allowing me to deploy it directly through profiles, so i was thinking to test it through downloading from appstore without sending it to review. sorry if i am troubling anyone :)

Comment: Nope, there's no way. It's ad hoc distribution or public AppStore distribution only. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can not upload to the app store without review process. period.

Large PDF's work in the simulator because the simulator runs on your computer which has lots more RAM than the iPhone.

You will need any iPhone or iPod Touch to test it. you could even use a friends.

Comment: guys, sorry if i am wrong, but is there any way that we can put our app on App store which will be applicable for some devices only(something like demo for inApp Purchase).Actually, i am making app on XCode 3.2 and the device is having IOS 5. so it is not allowing me to deploy it directly through profiles, so i was thinking to test it through downloading from appstore without sending it to review. sorry if i am troubling anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload to the App Store for testing purposes. You must either get hold of an iPhone to test or employ the services of a testing company who will have a whole suite of devices to test on.

Comment: guys, sorry if i am wrong, but is there any way that we can put our app on App store which will be applicable for some devices only(something like demo for inApp Purchase).Actually, i am making app on XCode 3.2 and the device is having IOS 5. so it is not allowing me to deploy it directly through profiles, so i was thinking to test it through downloading from appstore without sending it to review. sorry if i am troubling anyone :)